# Redirect everything but redirection page and images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all pages temporarily to another maintenance page for example, but I obviously don't want the page it gets redirected to to be redirected and I don't want images redirected either.

I have the below but I get a internal server error.. (I'm also allowing my IP)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/message.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /message.php [R=302,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get when you try to dereference /message.php

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: well, this isn't the main problem, but the image-matching RewriteCond line is missing a dot.  should be: `!^.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom pointed out your RewriteCond "starts with" `^` pattern `!^*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)` needs a dot like

`!^.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)`

or instead you can do an "ends with" match using `$` instead of a starts with wildcard match like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$
```

Comment: also you probably want to add .css to your exclusion list unless your maintenance page has no styling or its all hard coded. Same goes for .js if your maintenance page has any javascript references. And .ico if you have a favicon...